# Exercise about cyclic field extension

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

I am having hard time to solve following exercise.

Let $\Omega$ be the algebraic closure of a field $k$.

a) Suppose that every finite extension of $k$ is cyclic. Prove that it exists $\sigma \in Gal(\Omega / k)$ such that $k=\{x \in \Omega : \sigma(x)=x\}$.

b) For $\tau \in Gal(\Omega / k)$ and $K=\{x \in \Omega : \tau(x)=x\}$, prove that every finite extension of $K$ is cyclic.

For a) I'm trying to use Zorn lemma, but I'm going really nowhere.

Comment: Some ideas (hints) for (a): Isn’t it the case that for each $n\ge1$, there is at most one extension of $k$ of degree $n$? Isn’t there a sequence of integers $1|N_1|N_2|\cdots$ that’s cofinal with the set of degrees of extensions of $k$?